# How do you specify an external log4j properties file to start a jboss server?

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

How do you specify an external log4j properties file to run a jboss server with?

I need to do this with bash/ terminal commands? Not programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder to store `log4j.properties` (i.e `C:\PropertiesFolder`).
Then add the link to this folder to JBoss classpath:

1. Go to `[server folder]\bin`
2. Edit `run.bat` (if server is running on Windows) or `run.sh` (for Linux)
3. Edit classpath line by adding the folder link:

Snippet:

```
if "x%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%" == "x" (
  set "RUN_CLASSPATH=%RUNJAR%;C:\PropertiesFolder;"
) else (
  set "RUN_CLASSPATH=%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%;%RUNJAR%;C:\PropertiesFolder;"
)
```

Finally restart the server then run by command line (go to `[server folder]\bin` then type `run`)

Comment: how can you access the properties in java files?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the log4j.properties file in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If the target version of Jboss is **7.1.x** - then you need to follow the simple 2 steps, that are described in the official documentation.

***How do I use log4j.properties or log4j.xml instead of using the logging subsystem configuration?***

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F

Hope that helps