# Where to put property file in JBOSS 7 or Glassflish? (Best practice)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish

I have developed applications for JBOSS EAP 5 with eclipse. I placed property files under server-conf/conf/...
I am now developing in Netbeans (7.2). The bundled glassfish server is used for easier development. The target environment is JBOSS EAP 6. What is the best place to place property files? A common place for both environments would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have them external to the application you'll probably have to write a custom module. This isn't as bad as it sounds, check out [HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath).

See also [migration-issues-to-jboss-7-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400280/migration-issues-to-jboss-7-1)

Answer (score 0):

The most practical solution is creating a custom folder outside both JBOSS and Glassfish (i.e `C:\PropertiesFolder`) then add this folder to the classpath of each server.
Please read my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040936/how-do-you-specify-an-external-log4j-properties-file-to-start-a-jboss-server/12516178#12516178)for more details about classpath in JBoss