# Add property file to server

Tags: java, spring

I have to load some property files(eg:- email properties) at the time of the server(wildfly 9) starts. How can I add the file and How can I access that in my java code?

Comment: go and visit here : https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath

possible duplicate of :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562069/where-to-put-property-file-in-jboss-7-or-glassflish-best-practice

Comment: Are the properties needed by the server or by the application running on the server?

Comment: Application runs on the server

Answer (score 0):

Import the java utility properties `import java.util.Properties;`

Then create email.properties inside your WebContent/WEB-INF/ containing:

```
EMAIL:test@gmail.com
```

And access it like this:

```html
Properties props = new Properties();
  try {
   props.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("email.properties"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
    String email = props.getProperty("EMAIL");
```

String email will return 'test@gmail.com'

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Code for reading property file

```
Properties properties = new Properties();InputStream stream = null;try {stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(“propertyfile.properties”); properties.load(stream); String emailId = properties.getProperty(“email”);} catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace();} finally{stream.close();}
```